# Strange Twitter authorization error

Tags: perl, twitter

I'm trying to do a simple Twitter posting script and getting some strange results. This is the relevant code:

```
if ( $access_token eq "" || $access_token_secret eq "" ) {
    $nt = Net::Twitter->new(
        traits          => [qw/API::RESTv1_1 OAuth/],
        consumer_key    => $app_key,
        consumer_secret => $app_secret,
        ssl             => 1,
    );
} else {
    $nt = Net::Twitter->new(
        traits              => [qw/API::RESTv1_1 OAuth/],
        consumer_key        => $app_key,
        consumer_secret     => $app_secret,
        access_token        => $access_token,
        access_token_secret => $access_token_secret,
        ssl                 => 1,
    );
}
if ( !$nt->authorized ) {
    print "You must authorize this app at ", $nt->get_authorization_url, " and enter the PIN below.\n\nPIN: ";
}
```

The code fails on the $nt->get_authorization_url line with the following error:

```
Net::Twitter::Role::Oauth::get_authorization_url(): GET https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token failed: 401 Unauthorized
```

This makes no sense to me, why does it ask to be authorized in order to get the authorization URL...

Comment: Did you check your timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

Doh found out the cause, this is what happens when my VM's clock is set too far back. Thanks for the mention about timestamps to Leistungsabfall for making me think of checking that, and I wish the Twitter error message made more sense.